Pandas, how to pass a datetime64 dtype in a query without raising futur warning
Following google colab most recent update, i'm getting a futurewarning when using the query method on dtype datetime64:
"The behavior of 'isin' with dtype=datetime64[ns] and castable values (e.g. strings) is deprecated. In a future version, these will not be considered matching by isin. Explicitly cast to the appropriate dtype before calling isin instead."
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_dates' :[pd.Timestamp('2024-09-30 00:00:00'),
                                  pd.Timestamp('2024-09-23 00:00:00')]})

print(df.dtypes)
---output :
some_dates    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

df.query("some_dates in [('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")
---output :
<ipython-input-53-09d8c5b6f74b>:1: FutureWarning: The behavior of 'isin' with dtype=datetime64[ns] and castable values (e.g. strings) is deprecated. In a future version, these will not be considered matching by isin. Explicitly cast to the appropriate dtype before calling isin instead.
  df.query("some_dates in [('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")

some_dates
0   2024-09-30

using isin removes the warning :
df['some_dates'].isin([np.datetime64('2024-09-30 00:00:00')])
---output :

some_dates
0   True
1   False

dtype: bool

but i struggle to apply it to the query method :
df.query("some_dates in [np.datetime64('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")
---output : 
UndefinedVariableError: name 'np' is not defined

Edit : just found out that passing @pd.Timestamp(date) works :
df.query("some_dates in [@pd.Timestamp('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")
---output : 
some_dates
0   2024-09-30

However @np.datetime64 doesn't :
'''
df.query("some_dates in [@np.datetime64('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")
---output : 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy._ArrayFunctionDispatcher' and 'int'

'''

just found out that passing @pd.Timestamp(date) works :
df.query("some_dates in [@pd.Timestamp('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")
---output : 
some_dates
0   2024-09-30

However @np.datetime64 doesn't :
df.query("some_dates in [@np.datetime64('2024-09-30 00:00:00')]")
---output : 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy._ArrayFunctionDispatcher' and 'int'

